# Forcing SSL on signup but removing SSL on non-signup pages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, url-rewriting

I am using wordpress and I have the following two functions defined in wp-config.php:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
```

But I am also wanting to force SSL on a signup page of `example.com/signup-page` however if I navigate to the signup-page then navigate elsewhere on the website it keeps `https` enabled unless I go to the homepage...

I want the entire website to be forced to have `www.` and the force the entire website to be non-SSL with the exception of login forms, admin pages, `signup-page` and `custompage`

I tried the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(signup-page/.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't quite work, the signup-page bit works but if I navigate to any other page it keeps the https...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep these 2 rules as **your very first rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(signup-page|example-page) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+(signup-page|example-page) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Works pretty good...  how would I add more folders to the https setting... say if I wanted to do `signup-page` & `example-page`